# Easy game examples for Android

Tags: android, animation

I want to develop games for Android.

What are the best ways to do 2D games?

Are there some good resources on developing simple games for someone new to Android?

Comment: +1, you may start chatting now :)

Comment: please accept Kristiono Setyadi's answer as it's better with actual examples. Unaccept my answer as its old and not very informative in current year.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

***NOTICE*** : **I suggest to check out other answers with good examples. I have requested to unaccept this answer and accept https://stackoverflow.com/a/8322784/753603 answer**

---

Well it all depends where you stand in matter of Android platform and knowledge of how it works?

**Beginner**

Than I would suggest start writing simple apps to add some GUI background images, and get familiar with lots of different data structures and how to deal with them. Read about background task execution such as AsyncTask.

**Intermediate**

Explore different Graphics engines for Android, I would suggest

- http://www.andengine.org/

ANdEngine is game engine for android platform, It has lots of built in functionality which you can use for making games. Find tutorials on google there are lot lot lot and lot...and while I am writing this, some generous people are writing one for us :)

**Expert in making game on other platform**

Than also I would suggest google tutorials like this one,

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androidBallGame.aspx

Again there are heaps of them. :)

Cheers enjoy!

Comment: Good answer, but your first link is broken.

Comment: @RobinEllerkmann, Thanks for letting me know. Don't know why he/she deleted the answer. Oh well, I removed it now ;)

Answer (score 12):

You can start by reading the [Android documentation about Graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html). After that, you can try numerous tutorials and sample codes in the [Resources](http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html) section. There are sub-sections available for you to learn from the sample codes:

1. **JetBoy**
   http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/JetBoy/index.html
2. **Lunar Lander** http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html
3. **TicTacToe** http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/TicTacToeMain/index.html

and so on.

Working link for  [donut-release2 / samples](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/donut-release2/samples)

Comment: Links don't work anymore. Mirrors are available [here](https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples).

Answer (score 6):

Pretty Good documentation on [How do I get started making Android games](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3401/how-do-i-get-started-making-android-games) ,